# Email extended permission not granted in some cases

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I am using the server-side authentication flow, and when requesting the email extended permission, once in a blue moon the email address is not sent back, causing my application to break.

That information is required for my application to function properly, so I will modify it to re-prompt the user.  But I would like to understand why/how this happens since I cannot find any way to revoke that permission from the application when authorizing.  The dialog states that the permission is required.  Is this because of accounts belonging to minors that can't give out that information?

I'm requesting like so:  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=$fbAuthUrl&state=$stateString&scope=email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much head banging, I found this bug filed with Facebook that I think is responsible:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/487563591260030

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that some users simply won't have an email - Earlier, it was possible to sign up for Facebook with a cell phone only - I'm not sure if there's some other reason or, it could be a bug with the API